# A point minimizing total great circle distance to a given set of points on a hemisphere

Tags: geometry, optimization, spherical-geometry, median

If you have a set of points on a hemisphere, how do you find a point on that hemisphere that has the minimum total great circle distance to the points in the set.

Comment: Can't recall the name; in the plane, if you are given three points in an acute triangle, the optimum fourth point is in the interior of the triangle, such that the segments to the three triangle vertices meet at $120^\circ$  Similar on hemisphere. Given more than three points, rapidly gets messy.

Comment: So, the [geometric median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median) on a sphere?

Comment: @Rahul yes, now that you point that out, and specifically on the hemisphere, if that helps. I believe that a hemisphere guarantees that the geometric median will be unique, whereas on the sphere there could be an infinite number of points.

Comment: @WillJagy For a triangle, that's [Fermat point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point) but the generalization has been termed differently, as in Rahul's comment.

Comment: This is a norm minimization problem right? Assuming great circle distance is a norm on the space defined by points on a sphere, the problem reduces to minimizing the sum of the distances of some point $x$ from the given points $x_k$. I think that should be a convex minimization problem.